# running nohup command on script that takes all parameters

Tags: bash, nohup

I am trying to run a script with nohup, but the command happens to take an 
entire line of parameters with the variable $*.  I try running the command like this:

```
    nohup time ./build_all all &
```

But this is giving me the following error in nohup.out:

```
./build_all: DISPLAY=ted:0.0: is not an identifier
```

Any help appreciated.

Ted

==================================================================================

I realize that Peter John Acklam was right. The error is not because of nohup, but because of the script, I am not sure what I am doing wrong because the syntax seems correct to me. It is also kind of strange that when I run the script on its own, I don't see the error, but when I try to run with nohup, I see the strange error.

Anyhow, the beginning of the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=ted:0.0 # sets the display
export RELEASE=v1.0

node=`uname -n`
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply place the arguments to “build_all” on the command line, as for any other command:

```
nohup time ./build_all args to build_all go here &
```

and the arguments will be passed to “build_all”, not to “time” or “nohup”. The ampersand will be interpreted correctly by the shell, and will not be passed as an argument to any of the commands.

Comment: that's strange, that did not seem to work when I tried it. The error may have been somewhere else then.

Comment: I did as you suggested but, I actually get a strange error with the DISPLAY variable

Comment: The “DISPLAY” variable error is due to a syntax error in “build_all”, and has nothing to do with “nohup” or “time”. Perhaps you can show the line in “build_all” that contains the string “DISPLAY=ted:0.0”?

Comment: Well it looks like this:
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=ted:0.0 # sets the display
export RELEASE=v1.0

node_name=`uname -n`

Comment: The error appears because you are using “DISPLAY=ted:0.0” at a place where bash expects an identifier, i.e., something that can be used as the name of a variable, function etc.

The syntax in the code above is fine. I suspect the error is somewhere further down in your script.

Answer (score 1):

The script arguments (parameters) simply follow the script's name and preceed the ampersand.